# Find integers $x$ that satisfy $\tan{x}>10^{30}$

Tags: number-theory

I have a positive integer $x$. I want to find all values of $x$ that satisfy the following inequality: $$\tan{x}>10^{30}$$

I don't have much experience with number theory. How would one normally approach a problem like this? I tried brute forcing it by calculating $\tan(x)$ for increasing values of $x$, but the largest value I found was $\tan(122925461)\approx 10^9$, which is far smaller than the required $10^{30}$. Is there a more mathematical approach that could solve this problem?

Comment: A good idea should be to use the convegents of the simple continued fraction of $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: $$4368074519151556502674077262299885926704676221372633$$ does the job , for example.

Comment: Whether we get ALL such integers this way is another story.

Comment: Find $a < \pi/2$ so that $\tan x > 10^{30}$ in interval $(a,\pi/2)$.  Then we want to find integers $x, k$ so that $x+k\pi \in (a,\pi/2)$.  That is where the continued fraction would be useful.

Comment: Perhaps the smallest is $$1647533557310758242795542778250$$ , but I did not consider best-approximations not arising from the numerators of the convergents. So, this is no guarantee.

Comment: @Peter Oh, so if I have a continued fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ with sufficiently big $a$ and $b$, then I can do $\tan a$ and check the sign?

Comment: The denominator must be odd and it must be an "odd" convergent , if they are numbered beginning with $\frac{1}{1}$. I think (but have no idea how to prove it) that this gives infinite many solutions, but maybe not all.

Comment: For these question, do you allow the use of computing technology?

Comment: @Dan Sure! I tried brute forcing it at the beginning, but this time I'm trying to make a program to generate a convergent for $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us say we wish to find integer values of $x$ for which $\tan x>k>0$. Therefore,
$$
\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}>k
{\implies \begin{cases}\sin x-k\cos x>0&,\quad \cos x>0\\\sin x-k\cos x<0&,\quad \cos x<0\end{cases}
\\\implies \begin{cases}\sin \left(x-\theta\right)>0&,\quad \cos x>0\\\sin \left(x-\theta\right)<0&,\quad \cos x<0\end{cases}
\\
\implies \begin{cases}2u_1\pi+\theta<x<(2u_1+1)\pi+\theta&,\quad 2u_2\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}<x<2u_2\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}
\\
(2u_1+1)\pi+\theta<x<(2u_1+2)\pi+\theta&,\quad 2u_2\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}<x<2u_2\pi+\frac{3\pi}{2}
\end{cases}
,
}
$$
where $\theta=\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k^2}}$ and $u_1,u_2\in\Bbb Z$. Since $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$, it is easy to see that the intervals $(2u_1\pi+\theta,(2u_1+1)\pi+\theta)$ and $\left(2u_2\pi-\frac{\pi}{2},2u_2\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ have non-empty intersection if and only if $u_1=u_2$. Same is true for the intervals $((2u_1+1)\pi+\theta,(2u_1+2)\pi+\theta)$ and $\left(2u_2\pi+\frac{\pi}{2},2u_2\pi+\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{cases}2u_1\pi+\theta<x<(2u_1+1)\pi+\theta&,\quad 2u_2\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}<x<2u_2\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}
\\
(2u_1+1)\pi+\theta<x<2u_1\pi+\theta&,\quad 2u_2\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}<x<2u_2\pi+\frac{3\pi}{2}
\end{cases}
\iff
\\
\begin{cases}2u\pi+\theta<x<2u\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}&,\quad u\in\Bbb Z
\\
2u\pi+\pi+\theta<x<2u\pi+\frac{3\pi}{2}&,\quad u\in\Bbb Z.
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore, the set of integer solutions of $\tan x>k>0$ is
$$
\left\{x\in \Bbb Z: \exists u\in \Bbb Z, x\in \left(2u\pi+\theta,2u\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\cup \left(2u\pi+\pi+\theta,2u\pi+\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)\right\},
$$
where $\theta=\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{1+k^2}$.

Comment: Did you forget a square root sign for the last $\theta$?

Comment: Is the final answer more useful than $\{x\in\mathbb{Z}:\tan x>10^{30}\}$ ?

Comment: Well, the final answer boils $\tan x$ down to inequalities in terms of $x$, which may be more straightforward to deal with.